# Calculate sum of string of numbers from a file, while the numbers are in random rows

Tags: python, string, list, file-io, sum

I have a file with numbers that are in rows, with random amount of numbers in each row. And I need to calculate the sum.

My input is like so:

```
63,59,39,5,99,35,56
58,19,35,34,88,55,38,47,90
38,46,33,62,9,58,54,34,37
78,72,25,56,17
```

The code I have so far is:

```
def sumIs(file):
    line = file.readlines()
    lines = [line.split(",") for line in file]
    removed = [lines.rstrip('\n') for lines in file]
    for i in range(0, len(removed)):
        removed[i] = int(removed[i])
    a = sum(removed)
    return a
```

For some reason it returns a 0. While it suppose to be a sum of all the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def sumIs(f):
    # Open the file
    with open(f) as file:
        # read each line
        lines = file.readlines()

        # strip newline characters and split on commas
        line_list = [line.rstrip('\n\r').split(",") for line in lines]

        # Set up return variable
        rv = 0

        # Add the sum the integers in each line to the return variable
        for line in line_list:
            rv += sum(int(x) for x in line)

        return rv

print(sumIs('a.txt'))
```

Gives 1439 when passed your example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `file` is an opened file descriptor, you can do that entirely with list comprehensions:

```
def sumIs(file):
    lines = file.readlines()
    return sum([sum([int(val) for val in line.strip("\n").split(",")]) for line in lines])
```

you would initialize file like so:

```
file = open("path-to-file")
```

and you should close it after `sumIs` returns:

```
file.close()
```

An alternative to this is passing a filename and handling the opening
inside sumIs, as @CDJB did in their answer.